# FilePond revert uploads: the DELETE request does not contain unique ID. What to do?

Tags: reactjs, express, filepond

I am a beginner and I struggled for days with this problem

My problem is when I press the cross button to revert the file I just uploaded, it sends a DELETE request to the backend (I am using Express). However, the req.body is empty and the backend has no way to identify the files that the user wants to revert.

According to the [doc](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#revert), it says a unique ID is contained, but I just cannot find it. I wonder if I need to manually add something in the properties, but I don't know what to add. Below is my ReactJs code.

```
<FilePond
                                    files={files}
                                    onupdatefiles={setFiles}
                                    allowMultiple={true}
                                    maxFiles={10}
                                    name="image"
                                    instantUpload={true}
                                    allowReorder={true}
                                    labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
                                    itemInsertLocation='after'
                    

                                    // onprocessfiles={console.log('all files are uploaded!')}
                                    server={{url: "http://localhost:8080/adoptions",

                                            revert:{url:'/revert'}, 

                                             process:{
                                             url:'/process',
                                             method: 'POST',
                                             withCredentials: false,
                                             headers: {},
                                             timeout: 7000,
                                             onload: (res)=>{
                                                res = JSON.parse(res)
                                                console.log('RES:',res)
                                                console.log('res.filename:', res['msg'])
                                                pushToArrayAndLog(uniqueFileId,res.filename)
                                            },
                                            // onload: (response)=>response.key
                                            ondata: (formData) => {
                                                // getFileEncodeDataURL()
                                                // console.log(formData.values())
                                            // formData.append('extraField', this.id)
                                            return formData;
                                            }
                                             }}}

                                                />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique id should be returned by your server in the `process` end point.

I see you've implemented the `onload` hook which is used to pinpoint/select the unique id in a response. So let's assume your JSON response in `onload` has a `fileId` in the object. You'd return that id in the `onload` hook.

```js
process: {
  // other props
  onload: (res) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(res);
    return res.fileId; // FilePond passes this id to your server when you use the revert call
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem solved. As a programming beginner, may I ask where in the doc I can find out I just need to return id in the onload hook so the id is stored in the hidden field? (or I don't know how to call it)

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` is a method that is used to delete the resource at the URI you specify.

For example, a `DELETE` on `https://fileserver.example/file.zip` would mean that `file.zip` should get deleted.

So the target of the `DELETE` is the url itself. `DELETE` request should not have bodies and in many cases clients and servers drop the body. The fact that the Filepond documentation mentions a body for these requests tells me that either the documentation is incorrect, or they built their API incorrectly.

Comment: Oh yes! DELETE should not have req.body. So my other question is how to attach the file identifier to the URL? For example, when I click the cross button to revert File XYZ, I don't know where to find the file ID. What I know is in the React State value (which is an arrays of files) I can find the ID of search file.

Comment: I am very confused by the docs of FindPond, I don't know if it is my problem for not having a solid base of programming knowledge.

Comment: In this case I think Filepond is broken.

Comment: Do you think I should just dump the library? Or there should be some ways to get around?

Comment: @ufo unless you have other reasons to try and use something else, my first step would usually be to report a bug and give them a chance to fix the problem. As a software engineer I would hope someone would try to report a problem before they move on.

Comment: Dev here. I went with a request body when building FilePond, it worked without issue on PHP, so I thought nothing of it. It's not great, but it should work with Node as well. I'll address this in een new major release. In this case the issue is that there is no unique id returned by the process end point, or none is selected in the onload hook.

Comment: @Rik Sounds good! good luck

Comment: @Rik one thing I would add is that there's no guarantee this is going to work, including Node or browsers. *some* client in Node might allow this, and others will just strip the request body and neither would be *wrong*.